# What am I ? any guess?

Tags: riddle

Take away my first letter, then take away my second letter. Then take away the rest of my letters, yet I remain the same. What am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be I am wondering

> A postman?

Comment: you are wondering it right:)

Answer (score 2):

You are none other than a

> Mailbox.

Comment: No, but you're very close